# Understanding Pin Bars

Tags: investment-strategies, chart

I have troubles with `Pin Bars`. I read that they could show a trend reversal in the market. Can they be bullish and bearish and how do you tell if it is one (i.e. is there a percentage of body to shadow)?

If the body is so small that it *could* be seen as a `Doji` candle, what would be the difference. Wouldn't it be called `Grave Stone` or `Dragon Fly Doji` then?

And finally, does the direction of the longer shadow make the price direction or does the colour of the `Pin Bar` play a role, too?

Comment: The future price of anything cannot be predicted from knowledge of its price in the past.

Comment: @FiveBagger While I am in the forefront of people who believe that any sort of day trading is likely pointless for non-professionals, I would take exception to your statement that the future price of anything cannot be predicted from knowledge of its price in the past.  I know that a bottle of Coke Zero costs $1.89, and I predict tomorrow it will also be $1.89, both at my local Walgreens.  That predition is not 100% guaranteed to be true - it might go up to $1.99, or it might go on sale - but I have probably a 95% chance it's correct.

Comment: While this is less true for the stock market than for bottles of low calorie caffeinated beverages, there is still some ability to predict future prices based on past prices;  AAPL is likely to be around 105-115 tomorrow because it is today and has been in that neighborhood for a while.  Etc.  Nobody is claiming 100% accuracy, even the hardcore day traders, here - they're just claiming some degree of predictability based on patterns etc.  (Whether they get the degree they suggest they do, now, that's a better question...)

Comment: @FiveBagger - and yet, technical analysis appears to be on topic, see [Do we want technical analysis questions?](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/669/do-we-want-technical-analysis-questions). I do need to update the official on-topic list, but i think the discussion itself is behind us.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer While reading your link I got the impression that questions like mine are within the scope of MoneySE. Am I in the wrong place?

Comment: @Alexej  please reread my comment, I think you took it backwards. I was responding to fivebaggers comment. I don't have to be a fan of TA or answer questions on it, but I do respect our own On Topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
   *I read that pin bar could show a trend reversal in the market.*
```

Alexej, you asked five different questions in your post... Next time, separate please.

**Can they be bullish and bearish ?** Yes, both depending on the candles before.

**How do you tell the difference ?** Difficult to say. It depends. You cannot use this formation alone, you have to consider the group of candles before your so called Pin Bar.

**Is there a percentage of body to shadow?** No, candle stick charting is mostly based on visual interpretation, but sometimes 50% is a good percentage to look for.

**If the body is so small** that it could be seen as a Doji candle, **what would be the difference ?** None. Again candle stick analysis is visual and based on experience. Sometimes it's bullish, sometimes bearish. The correct interpretation comes with experience.

**Wouldn't it be called Grave Stone or Dragon Fly Doji then?** These so called "pin bars" are in fact hammer and hanging man candlesticks. It's a question of words. The author you read is coining words.

**Does the direction of the longer shadow make the price direction or does the colour of the Pin Bar play a role, too?** They go together, the shadow shows rejection of a certain price level. It indicates a move opposite to the direction of the rejection. The move is in the direction of the body not the shadow.

**Your sources:** I suspect your reading come from a website advertising "Forex trading made easy" or the like. There are a lot of those around.  Many are investor's traps in my opinion.

I would suggest that you **refer to the classic texts** on [candlestick charting](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:chart_analysis:introduction_to_candlesticks#further_study) **instead of** refering to website dedicated to selling their Ebooks, special courses and private coaching for Forex trading. Yes, **candlestick charting is the best** way to time the markets, but you learn by experience. Join this [candlestick trading forum](http://www.candlestickforum.com/PPF/Parameters/1_25_/candlestick.asp) to learn. I am still learning every day. Happy trading to you.